# Unnecessary CSS property causing all manner of problems for UserScripts

Tags: bug, status-completed, css

The CSS for both Ask Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu Meta contains a useless CSS value. (When I say useless, I mean that it doesn't affect the page at all if removed.)

[image]

As you can see, the `.container` for the page contains the CSS style `position: relative;` and I have no idea why because none of the other StackExchange sites have that property set.

The reason it needs to be removed is because it's breaking at least two of my UserScripts that absolutely position content on the page.

Comment: If it's so important for your user script, and you say it doesn't break anything, why don't you just have your user script set it back to `static`? Or don't put your absolutely positioned elements into `.container`?

Comment: @balpha: It's easier not to have exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed position: relative. The change will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I often set a global `position:relative` on containers. Makes development easier if they all behave the same way.

But that's besides the point... I think you're doing it wrong. If you need something to display outside the confines of a container, logically speaking, one would inject their HTML outside the container.

Comment: It *is* outside the container :P